# Orion CB: How to store a string attribute containing a quote (") character

Tags: fiware-orion

We tried several different kinds of update requests to Orion broker in order to give an attribute a string value containing a quote (") character. Result was always "Bad request" and detail was "Illegal value for JSON field" or "JSON parse error". We tried 1 to 4 backslash (\) characters preceding the quote for escaping a couple of levels but no help. The ultimate purpose is to store a structured value in JSON format.

Comment: Just to confirm, which Orion version are you using (i.e., the output of `contextBroker --version`)?

Comment: Does this help: <br>:~$ curl orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026 --version<br>
    curl 7.27.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.27.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: Debug GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP

Comment: Doesn't really help.
If you execute 'your own' broker, start it with the --version option:

    $ contextBroker --version

If not, use curl, with "<ip:port>/version", e.g.:

    $ curl localhost:1026/version

Answer (score 0):

Since Orion 0.17.0, quot (") is a [forbidden character](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Forbidden_characters) due to security reasons. However, it can be easily escaped by the client, e.g. using `%22` with the [URL encoding scheme](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php).